# Should an AWS Lambda function instance in Node.js pick up another request during an async await?

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda

Let's say I've got a queue of requests for my Lambda, and inside the lambda might be an external service call that takes 500ms, which is wrapped in async await like

```
async callSlowService(serializedObject: string) Promise<void>{
    await slowServiceClient.post(serializedObject);
}
```

Should I expect that my Lambda instance will pick up another request off the queue while awaiting the slow call? I know it'll also spin up new Lambda instances but that's not what I'm talking about interleaving requests on a *single instance*.

I'm asking because I would think that it should do this, however I'm testing with a sleep function and a load generator and it's not happening. My code actually looks like this:

```
    async someCoreFunction() Promise<void>{
        // Business logic 
        console.log("Before wait");
        await sleep(2000);
        console.log("After wait");
    }
}

const sleep = (milliseconds) => {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, milliseconds))
};
```

And while it definitely is taking 2 seconds between the "Before wait" and "After wait" statements, there's no new logs being written in that time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

Lambda as a service is largely unaware of what your code is doing. It simply takes a request, invokes your code and then waits for it to return.

I would not expect AWS to implement a feature like interleaving any time soon. It would require the lambda runtime to have substantial knowledge of how your code behaves (for example, you may be awaiting two concurrent long asynchronous calls within one invocation- so simply interrupting when you hit your first await would be incorrect). It would also cause no end of issues for people using the shared scope outside of the handler for common setup/teardown.

As you pay per invocation and time, I don't really see that there is much difference between interleaving and processing the queue in parallel (which lambda natively supports); considering that time spent awaiting still requires some compute. If interleaving ever happens I'd expect it to be a way for AWS to reduce the drain on their own resources.

n.b. If you are awaiting for a long time in a lambda function then there is probably a better way of doing things. For example, Step Functions provide a great way to kick off and poll long running tasks. Similarly, the pattern of using a session variable in your payload is a good way of allowing a long service to callback into lambda without having the lambda idling.